# location.hash navigate forward/backward through browser history

Tags: jquery

I used [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/Azxjt/) to create my form. How can I create the `location.hash`?

For example, I'm in the first part of the form `www.example.com/form#step1`, if I click `next`
I go to the next part of the form `www.example.com/form#step2`. Now I want to get back to the previous part of the form which is if I hit back on the browser, I go to the previous form which is `www.example.com/form#step1` and all my inputs are still there.

I tried something with `location.hash` and `location.href` but it doesn't work.

Comment: The reason you're not allowed to post a link to JS Fiddle (or why you're not able to post an answer with a link *to* JS Fiddle) is because you've not included the code in your question. Please don't try and circumvent that error message by obfuscating your link text; just include the code.

Comment: Please include the code you already tried which did not work

Comment: this is what i've got so far
http://jsfiddle.net/Azxjt/13/